# boostrap columns same heights with fieldsets

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap columns have fieldset which I am trying make same heights for columns. For same height I am using following this article [Bootstrap 3 responsive columns of same height](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height) But this is applying for fieldset. I have example here.

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jfwefLgx/)

Comment: Please don't side-step the warning you were given about linking to JSFiddle. **Include relevant code in the question**.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have set 100% height for fieldset, the parent height is unknown. Set the parent div containers height to 100%. You need to make below changes.

**CSS**

```
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* fix overflow */
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-xs-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/jfwefLgx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to be the same heights for both elements you need to structure your `table` data correctly. This means adding a `table-row` DIV just after your `.row-same-height` class.

```
<div class="row-same-height">
  <div class="tablerow">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-height col-top">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-height col-top">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then I adjusted the CSS accordingly adding the `height:100%` to your table, table-row and table-cell elements.

```
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
.tablerow {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-top {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can [see your updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfwefLgx/2/). Hope that helps.